# API 'search' method with 'min' parameter

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, api, search

If you search for questions posted on time `1296897085` or later (by specifying `sort=creation` and `min=1296897085`), it may still return questions posted before that date:

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/search?tagged=java;algorithm&sort=creation&min=1296897085&pagesize=2

In this case, it returns a question posted one second before (`1296897084`). But the gap can be more: e.g. specifying min date as `1296897100` still gives that question, but `1296898100` does not.

So, `min` seems to be 'inexact' restriction.

This is not a stopper bug, as I can filter returned questions manually, but I thought it's still worth reporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The granularity on /search results has changed out of necessity.

Searches now bound queries as a "best effort," which for creation/activity tends be within about a minute (give or take).

Comment: Actually, they're often off by 5 minutes and more, depending on the number of search tags. Many are missed completely if you scan with 5-minute window, others come clustered together.  It seems, using 'search' method for this is simply impractical: it's much better to go for 'questions' and filter result by tags on client side.

Comment: @Nikita - if all you want is questions in a tag, just use the `tagged` parameter on `/questions`.  Search is for a very rare, needs a match in the title, case.